# Splitting a text file based on empty lines in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am working on a really big file which is a very large text document almost 2GBs.

Something like this -

```
\#\*MOSFET table look-up models for circuit simulation
\#t1984
\#cIntegration, the VLSI Journal
\#index1

\#\*The verification of the protection mechanisms of high-level language machines
\#@Virgil D. Gligor
\#t1984
\#cInternational Journal of Parallel Programming
\#index2

\#\*Another view of functional and multivalued dependencies in the relational database model
\#@M. Gyssens, J. Paredaens
\#t1984
\#cInternational Journal of Parallel Programming
\#index3

\#\*Entity-relationship diagrams which are in BCNF
\#@Sushil Jajodia, Peter A. Ng, Frederick N. Springsteel
\#t1984
\#cInternational Journal of Parallel Programming
\#index4
```

I want to read them in spark and split them based on the empty blocks in spark and create blocks of these data in PySpark.

`#*Entity-relationship diagrams which are in BCNF #@Sushil Jajodia, Peter A. Ng, Frederick N. Springsteel #t1984 #cInternational Journal of Parallel Programming #index4`

The code I currently wrote is
`rdd = sc.textFile('acm.txt').flatMap( lambda x : x.split("\n\n") )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to read this text file in spark and have one record per paragraph. For that, you can change the record delimiter (which is `\n` by default) like this:

In scala:

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","\n\n")
val rdd = sc.textFile("acm.txt")
```

In python (you need to access the java spark context to have access to the hadoop configuration):

```py
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","\n\n")
rdd = sc.textFile("acm.txt")
```

Comment: I tried this and it works thanks mate! New to PySpark!